# How to align edges of certain levels in forest package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I have a two-column document and created the following tree:

[image]

As you can see, the third level overlaps with the text of the other column.
To address this issue, I want to place the children `Hotel1234567890` and `Golf12345` slightly above their parent node and `Lima12345678` and `Kilo12345` slightly below the parent node to efficiently use the empty space.

The ideal end result would be something like this:

[image: result]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\title{Bla}
\author{John Doe}
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure} 
    \centering  
    
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      align=center,
      l=1em, l sep+=0em,anchor=base west,inner sep=0.1pt,outer sep=0pt,
       edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
      for root={
        parent anchor=east,
      },
    }
    [Main BLA,rotate=90,child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center
      [Quebec1234
            [Romeo
                ]
            [Sierra
                ]
      ]
      [Papa123456789]
      [Oscar1234567]
      [Juliet 123 45679
        [November123
            [Kilo12345]
                [Lima12345678]
        ]
        [Mike12345]
      ]
      [Alpha123
          [India12345]
          [Foxtrot1234567891
            [Golf12345]
            [Hotel1234567890]
          ]
          [Echo123456]
          [Delta12345]
          [Charlie123]
          [Bravo12345]
     ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
    \caption{Blah}
    \label{fig:bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I think this can be solved by creating two new edge styles specifically for the two special cases. However, I am not sure how the `edge path` needs to be designed to accommodate these requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure} 
\centering  
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      align=center,
      l=1em, l sep+=0em,anchor=base west,inner sep=0.1pt,outer sep=0pt,
       edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
      for root={
        parent anchor=east,
      },
    }
    [Main BLA,rotate=90,child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center
      [Quebec1234
            [Romeo
                ]
            [Sierra
                ]
      ]
      [Papa123456789]
      [Oscar1234567]
      [Juliet 123 45679
        [November123,parent anchor=-165
            [Kilo12345,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(5pt,-20pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x-=52pt,y-=25pt}]
            [Lima12345678,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(5pt,-20pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x-=52pt,y-=25pt}]
        ]
        [Mike12345]
      ]
      [Alpha123
          [India12345]
          [Foxtrot1234567891,parent anchor=20
            [Golf12345,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(5pt,20pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x-=25pt,y+=28pt}]
            [Hotel1234567890,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(5pt,20pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x-=25pt,y+=28pt}]
          ]
          [Echo123456]
          [Delta12345]
          [Charlie123]
          [Bravo12345]
     ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\caption{Blah}
\label{fig:bla}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.